# Android tablet avd screen distorted

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I created a Nexus 10 AVD to test my android app. In this AVD, the UI elements in the AVD are shown distorted.

[image]

For example, in above button, it can be seen that the bottom margin is not a straight line. This is more visible in some line charts of my application.

I take tablet screenshots for uploading into Google Play store listing. So I need the screen to be shown correctly, without any distortion.

Does anyone know how to get this fixed?

Comment: After getting the screenshot, did the image look like this?

Comment: @NigamPatro Yes. Screenshot looks exactly the same as the screen